# Certificate credentials for WCF service on an Azure cloud service signed by our own CA

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-security, azure-cloud-services

We have front and back end cloud service that communicate via WCF services which are secured using certificate credentials. The problem we are having is that the request fails with the following error:

```
           verb="POST"
           authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE" activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-0400-0080000000F7}"
           failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
           statusCode="403.16"
           triggerStatusCode="403.16"
```

(From IIS failed request tracing)

I believe the issue is as described here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/252657/iis-5.0-http-403.16-forbidden-client-certificate-untrusted-or-invalid
(That the server does not trust third party CAs by default. )

If I do as described in the link the issue is resolved but the cloud service isn't part of a domain and I don't know how to apply this setting as part of the deployment or programmatically as part of the start-up.

What I also find strange is that this issue doesn't seem common even though I presume securing WCF communications on Azure cloud services using certificates isn't unusual, so I wonder if the issue is a symptom of something else I am doing wrongly.

Comment: From my experience, we can use cloud service startup task to trust the certificate. For more details about the command line, please refer to [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732061(v=ws.10).aspx). The front and backend means cloud service Web Role and worker role? Do you use worker role as your WCF service? Do you use DIP as worker endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Both front and back ends are cloud service web roles. The front end calls the back end by a registered domain name (VIP, I suppose). The certificates are installed correctly via C# code in the OnStart method, and the app pool identity has access to the required private keys. As I mentioned, if I allow third party CAs and reboot it works.